# Mandrill - messages moved to spam because of [Caution: Message contains Redirect URL content]

Tags: email, laravel-4, mandrill

My Laravel Web App regularly sends out notifications about system changes via Mandrill.

Unfortunately, all mails sent by Mandrill are moved to my spam-box with the message:

> [Caution: Message contains Redirect URL content]

Question 1:

What is this message about? I think it's because my server sets the sender-address to "noreply@domain.com"

Question 2:

Is there any possibility to prevent that? Maybe there are just some additional configs needed.

---

**Additional Informations:**

- The receiving mail-server is based in my company. Mails are checked through the Symantec Messaging Gateway. The description from Symantec is:

> Redirect URLs include free hosting sites, URL shortening services, and
>   URL redirecting services which can potentially be abused to deliver
>   spam or malware payloads. Symantec Messaging Gateway can filter
>   against email messages that contain one or more redirect URLs.

- My email-program is MS Outlook 2010

Here is also the html-template of the mail I want to send:

```
   <body bgcolor="#f7f7f7">
    <table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="container-for-gmail-android" width="100%">
      <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top" width="100%" style="background:repeat-x url(##obfuscated##) #ffffff;">
          <center>
          <img src="##obfuscated##" class="force-width-gmail">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" bgcolor="#ffffff" background="##obfuscated##" style="background-color:transparent">
              <tr>
                <td width="100%" height="80" valign="top" style="text-align: center; vertical-align:middle;">

                  <center>
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" class="w320">
                      <tr>
                        <td class="pull-left mobile-header-padding-left" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                        <a href=""><img width="167" height="35" src="##obfuscated##" alt="logo"></a>
                        </td>

                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </center>

                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </center>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top" width="100%" style="background-color: #f7f7f7;" class="content-padding">
          <center>
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600" class="w320">
              <tr>
                <td class="header-lg">
                  Hallo {{$name}}!
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="free-text">
                  Just a text
                </td>
              </tr>

            </table>
          </center>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top" width="100%" style="background-color: #ffffff;  border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5; border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;">
          <center>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" class="w320">
              <tr>
                <td class="content-padding">
                  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                      <td class="header-md">
                        Just a text
                        <!-- something like:
                        <tr><td style="padding: 10px 10px 10px 0px;text-align: left;">'.$offline_posting->link.'</td><td style="padding: 10px 30px 10px 0px;">'.$offline_posting->job_id.'</td><td style="padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;color: red;">offline</td></tr> -->
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="padding-bottom: 75px;">
                  <table>
                    {{$postingslist}}
                  </table>


                </td>
              </tr>
                        <tr>
                <td class="button">
                  <div><!--[if mso]>
                    <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://188.166.43.201/" style="height:45px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:155px;" strokecolor="#ffffff" fillcolor="#73479c">
                      <w:anchorlock/>
                      <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:regular;">check changes</center>
                    </v:rect>
                  <![endif]--><a class="button-mobile" href="http://188.166.43.201/"
                  style="background-color:#73479c;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:'Cabin', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:regular;line-height:45px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:155px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;mso-hide:all;">check changes</a></div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </center>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top" width="100%" style="background-color: #f7f7f7; height: 100px;">
          <center>
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600" class="w320">
              <tr>
                <td style="padding: 25px 0 25px">
                  <strong>Heading</strong><br />
                  Coding by <a href="mailto:#myemail#">Me</a><br />
                  &copy; 2015 some company<br /><br />
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </center>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution for myself:

On the first hand, it was indeed the button "check changes", which declarated the Mail as fishing-mail, but didn't help with the prefix **[Caution: Message contains Redirect URL content]**

This was caused of the fact that I was sending an entire HTML-document including

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Removing the according lines solved the problem.

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 2):

It's going to depend on your receiving mail server why it's appending that message or noting that - since the message says something about redirect URL content, then you'll want to look at the URLs in the message - but that's just a guess - we'd need to know what spam filter or mail program you're using since they're all going to work a bit differently.

Some spam filters flag emails that contain tracking URLs, but not all. Others flag content when the text in the email looks like it's pointing to Site A, but the HTML actually points the link to Site B (ie, something designed to make you think you're really going to Paypal but that points you to a phishing site).

Here's an example. If you're sending something like this to Mandrill for processing:

```
<a href="http://example.com">example.com</a>
```

When Mandrill's tracking link gets applied, it'll appear in the email like the below, which looks phishy since it *looks* like you're being directed to example.com but in reality are going to a Mandrill/tracked link first:

```
<a href="http://mandrill.com/track....">example.com</a>
```

To address this, make sure the text that appears isn't a URL. So send something like this:

```
<a href="http://example.com">Click here to go to my site</a>
```

The above is mostly educated guess based on the message being displayed in your mail program - again, it's going to vary, so knowing more about that is/would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your very helpful answer. I've added some additional Informations to my question. Personally, I can't see a link containing a text that looks like an URL. 

My reporting also contains several URL-Strings to webpages, that aren't available any more. I recognized that Office put a link on them... or is it Mandrill?